# Pandoc unable to create a pagebreak when converting from markdown to docx

Tags: markdown, docx, pandoc

I'm trying to create a docx from my markdown file using

`pandoc test.md -o test.docx --reference-doc=template.docx`

and it works besides that pagebreak does not seem to happen not matter what i try.

the reference-doc is to set things like a header and footer, also colors for headers and such things.

I've tried the following

```
break before
\newpage
break after


break before2 
<w:p><w:r><w:br w:type=\"page\"/></w:r></w:p>
break after2


Paragraph before page break.

\pagebreak

First paragraph on a new page


PParagraph before page break.

***

First paragraph on a new pagearagraph before page break.

<!---<w:p><w:r><w:br w:type="page"/></w:r></w:p>--->
::: PageBreak
:::
First paragraph on a new page
<br>

<div class="pagebreak" />
asdf
::: PageBreak
:::
::: PageBreak2
:::
::: {custom-style="PageBreak"}
:::
::: {custom-style="PageBrea2"}
:::
::: pagebreak
:::
```

but nothing creates a pagebreak

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [*pagebreak* Lua filter](https://github.com/pandoc-ext/pagebreak). That should be the easiest and most general solution.